# mysql syntax for querystring and textbox to listview help

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Hey im trying to make a query string for my sqldatasource, the datasource is for a mysql database so its different from the normal query string for a ms db

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gymwebsite2ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gymwebsite2ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 

SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + ? + '%'">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="FirstName" QueryStringField="TextBox1.Text" 
            Type="String" />
```

Just wondering if this line is correct:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + ? + '%'">`
```

Also how do I get a listview to not post anything before I type in the querystring? At the moment as soon as the page is loaded the listview control trys to load data (unsuccessfuly) im trying to bind my textbox and button to the listview so when I type in a name and hit the button i get a return on my listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that line is correct, MySQL and SQL almost have the same syntax.